# InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender. Send email form support@mydomain.com

Tags: google-app-engine, email, google-apps

First of all: I have read the other questions with similar title, but this question is slightly different.

I am having trouble trying to use my own email (support@mydomain.com) to send email from appengine. I know that I have to register the email address as an Owner or Developer in App Engine -> Administration -> Permissions, but it is not possible to register support@mydomain.com. I have also tried to register a new google account with this email, but the mail that is added to Permissions is mydomain@gmail.com...

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail

I've read the grey note in the link above, but I was wondering if there was any workaround. The only thing I want to do is to send emails, and I do not want to register my domain at Google and pay for it.

Do you have any suggestions? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For abuse-avoidance reasons, App Engine only allows sending email from an authorized address. There is a workaround in that you can set `reply_to` property of mail message which will make it appear to the recipient as if that address sent it when they reply.

A more cumbersome way is to register a full blown google apps for that domain and then set that address as the sender, but it's really a heap of trouble.

Comment: Thanks. That is the best solution so far. I registered at Google Apps, but it's only a trial. If I have to pay for it I guess I have to set up email in another way.

Comment: @stianlp agree that depending on Google Apps it's truly limiting. And the AppEngine team just doesn't want to deal with separating AppEngine from Google Apps. Lots of people have been almost begging the App Engine team for the last 2-3 years, and they have yet to do anything about it.